# Typescript non-null validation function

Tags: typescript

Sorry if there are duplicates of this question. I'm having a hard time coming up with search terms that give relevant results.

My use case is that I want to check if a variable is not "empty" or that it is specifically not `null`, `undefined`, or an empty string. Like this:

```js
const myVar: string | null | undefined;

if (myVar === null || myVar === undefined || myVar.trim() === '') return;

const nonNullVar: string = myVar;
```

Typescript is smart enough to know that if the code gets passed the `if` check, then `myVar` is definitely a string. However, I would like to do this check multiple times, so I wrote a function for it:

```js
function isEmpty(val: string | null | undefined) {
    return val === null || val === undefined || val.trim() === '';
}

// ...

const myVar: string | null | undefined;

if (isEmpty(myVar)) return;

const nonNullVar: string = myVar;
```

But typescript is no longer able to infer that `myVar` is not empty, so it throws an error.

Does typescript have some way to signify that my method ensures non-nullness? I know I can use a non-null assertion (!), but I'm trying to avoid disabling the eslint rule for it as I don't want my team using it as a work around for actually checking their variables.

Comment: One thing to consider is that all those (empty trying, null, undefined) are falsey, so you can just use myVal && (code here that requires it to be defined and non-empty), or use a ternary expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type it as follows:

```
function isEmpty(val: string | null | undefined): val is null|undefined {
  return val === null || val === undefined || val.trim() === ''; 
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: You specified the type wrong after `val is`. It should be the type you're narrowing down to, string in this instance, not null | undefined (though I don't think there's a way to specify a non empty string)

Comment: @Nathan that sounds like it should be isNotEmpty

Comment: Ah yeah my bad, I thought he was asking for inverted :facepalm:

Comment: @Nathan I can confirm that Evert's code works as-is

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evert! I had no idea about type narrowing.

Comment: @Troncoso added the colon!

Comment: Although actually there's still a bug in your code, is should be `is null | undefined | string`, since an empty string `isEmpty`. So it's not really narrowing the type down in this instance, though the function will work.

Comment: @Evert yeah, I misread it. Though see my comment after. This isn't the best example of type narrowing just because isEmpty doesn't inform you what type it is, just what it could be (including string). Type narrowing is pretty cool though :)